# Re-import module "as"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found quite a few answers regarding the question how to re-import a module (e.g. after I changed it during programming), but I want to re-import it `as`. In other words I would like to repeat

```
import main.mydir.mymodule as mymod
```

and have my changes incorporated into my console without restarting the console.

What I am trying currently when I try to reload is the following. I might run

```
import main.warp.optimisation as opt
res = opt.combiascend(par)
```

then I do some changes, for example I put a `print('Yes, this worked.')` at the end of the method `combiascend`, then I run

```
import importlib
import main
importlib.reload(main)
importlib.reload(main.warp.optimisation)
opt = main.warp.optimisation
res = opt.combiascend(par)
```

This does not work: I am not getting any error, but changes I did in the module `optimisation` just were not applied. In my example, I do not get the respective output.

Comment: What does it mean it does not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: @sophros: I clarified.

Answer (score 2):

After employing one of those other answers to "refresh" `main.mydir.mymodule`, simply do:

```
mymod = main.mydir.mymodule
```

Looks like `importlib` also updates the reference you give it, so if the original import used an alias, you can simply reimport the alias. Given empty `foo/__init__.py` and `foo/bar/__init__.py`, and a `foo/bar/test.py` containing this:

```
def func():
    print("a")
```

Then I get this:

```
>>> import foo.bar.test as mod
>>> mod.func()
a
>>> import importlib
>>> # (Updating the file now to print b instead)
>>> importlib.reload(mod)
<module 'foo.bar.test' from '/home/aasmund/foo/bar/test.py'>
>>> mod.func()
b
```

Comment: Does this really work?  I've never imported modules this way (doesn't mean it's wrong though).  Wouldn't it be better to use importlib.reload(mymod) instead?

Comment: @tnknepp: That doesn't (re)import the module (and I said it would be necessary to perform the reload with your chosen mechanism first) - it requires `main.mydir.mymodule` to already have been imported - but it does create an alias for it. Try `import os.path; p = os.path; print(type(p)); print(p.join("a", "b"))`, which prints `<class 'module'>` and `a/b`.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset: I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I add some code to my question.